# What is the meaning of "founding" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

[Wikipedia's article on Mozilla Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Corporation#People) states:

> Most Mozilla Foundation employees transferred to the new organization at Mozilla Corporation's founding.

*found* is a verb and foundation is the noun, not founding. So what is the meaning of *at Mozilla Corporation's founding*?

Comment: The possessive *Corporation's* should have clued you in, Jason, that *founding* must be a noun there, formed from the verb *to found*.

Comment: Right regarding it being a noun, it helps but, i was stuck between the act of founding or a place.

Comment: Aha, I see. The preposition "at" can be used with time and place.  At 6AM....at the beginning of the movie...at the stadium.

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one noun to go with found:

- You know "**foundation**", which here is

  > "An institution supported by an endowment, often one that provides funds for charities, research, etc." ([Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/foundation?showCookiePolicy=true))
- but there is the term "**founding**", too, describing

  > "The activity or process of beginning an institution..." [(Collins)](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/founding?showCookiePolicy=true)

So, in plain English: When the "Mozilla Corporation" was set up, many employees came from the mother company "Mozilla Foundation". (With the name part "Foundation" here stating the legal type of institution.)

Comment: But that question was entirely answerable with a dictionary (as shown above), so I'll have to VTC.

Comment: I am an English learner. Probably, what I needed to know here was the meaning of at as a time indicator not of a place.

Comment: I checked the dictionary. Tbere was no such noun as  _founding_ listed under entry _found_.

Comment: Actually top Google hits returned found (verb) for the term founding. For me this was a tricky word.

Comment: That's why you should use a reputable source, preferably an english-english dictionary. Merriam-Webster, Collins or the Oxford English Dictionary come to mind.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I have Oxford Advanced 8 on my computer, but not the two others. Oxford also brought the verb not the noun.

Answer (score 1):

Founding is used as a noun in this case. It could have been replaced by "creation" used as a noun.

If I would have written that sentence I would have used "creation" as it provides a more concrete meaning.